# Unable to fetch dynamic data for antd table dataSource

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

I'm new to React so bear with me.

I'm trying to pull data from Postgres via Express into a React Antd front end table.  I have the table columns rendering correctly.  However the body of the table (data returned from Express) is not appearing.  Additionally, I can see the fetch for `/profilesTable` within the browser returning the intended data.  However, that data is not being passed into the table tag in the return statement.  I'm not sure why.

How can I pass data from `/profileTable` into the table correctly?

```
const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>
    },
    {
        title: 'Create Date',
        dataIndex: 'created_at',
        key: 'created'
    },
    {
        title: 'Created By',
        dataIndex: 'created_by',
        key: 'createdBy'
    }
]

function App() {
    const [dataFromPg , setDataFromPg]=useState(null);
      useEffect(() => {

        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await fetch('/profileTable')
            setDataFromPg(response);
        }
        fetchData();
        
    },[]);
      
      return (
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataFromPg}/>
      )
}
```

Comment: does your response field is the array to show in table?

Comment: No, the response data does not show.  Only the columns show in the table.  My hunch is that I have an issue with the async nature of fetch and how I'm trying to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I needed to await the response before committing it to the setData variable.  Below is a working version of the code.

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('/profileTable');
          const newData = await response.json();
          setData(newData);
        };

        fetchData();
      }, []);
      
      return (
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}/>
      )
}
```